# How to change style of ONE word to bold in text of RichTextBoxColumn added to DataGridView in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have added a RichTextBoxColumn to DataGridView, want to change font style 
Bold/Regular Font, ForeColor of a PART OF TEXT. But this does not work like Windows 
RichTextBox Control. Please help.
My Code:

```
With DataGridView1
    .Columns(4).DisplayIndex = 4
    .Columns(4).ValueType = GetType(DataGridViewRichTextBoxCell)
    .Columns(4).Width = 17
    .Columns(4).DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font(FontFamily 
    Name, 
    11.0!,System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)
End With
```

But, all Cells in Row get Bold.

Comment: Can you please post the code you worked on, to see what you did so far?

Comment: With DataGridView1.Columns(4).Name = "Particulars"
     .Columns(4).DataPropertyName = "Particulars"
     .Columns(4).HeaderText = "Particulars"
     .Columns(4).DisplayIndex = 4
     .Columns(4).ValueType = GetType(DataGridViewRichTextBoxCell)
    .Columns(4).Width = 17
    .Columns(4).DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("SEAGOE UI SEMIBOLD", 11.0!,      System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)
End With
But, all Cells in Row get Bold.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and post the code there? In StackOverflow you can edit code in the question to make is easier to read - by adding 4 spaces in the beginning of each line. It may help us help you.

Comment: Cells in a `DataGridView` do not contain controls by default. It's only while a cell is in editing mode that a control is embedded in it.  For instance, a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` doesn;t contain any `TextBox` control except when a cell is being edited. Your column would presumably be the same. You'll need to place the appropriate cell in edit mode in order to have a `RichTextBox` control embedded in the cell, at which point you can modify the text and formatting like you would any other `RichTextBox`.

Comment: Thanks jmcilhinney, I could do :  Dim cel As DataGridViewCell = DataGridView1(4, 0)
DataGridView1.CurrentCell = cel
DataGridView1.BeginEdit(True)
cel.Value = "This is my STRING" 
If cel.IsInEditMode Then cel.DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font(FontFamilyName, 12.0!, FontStyle.Bold)
BUT, nothing happened.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. David Wilson, I tried such presentation of my question, but could not do that. I would love to learn it.